# C: convert argv[1] to double

Tags: c

I need to pass a double to my program, but the following does not work:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

double ddd;

ddd=atof(argv[1]);

printf("%f\n", ddd);

return 0;
}
```

If I run my program as `./myprog 3.14` it still prints `0.000000`.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: Did you get any errors/warnings from your compiler when you tried to compile this?

Comment: Did you mean it returns 0 or prints 0? Because you told it to return 0 on the last line.

Comment: I have clarified my question. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is you forgot to include `#include <stdlib.h>`. If this is the case, `gcc` will issue the following warning:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'atof' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

And give the exact output you provided: `0.000000`.

Comment: (Are you trying to make some point about the effects of low reputation? :-))

Comment: adding `#include <stdlib.h>` solved the problem. But strangely, `gcc` did not issue any warnings without stdlib.h

Comment: @MartinVegter: Are you sure you said `gcc -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`?

Comment: Take home message here should be: people should include important parts of the code as the `#include`s and the output of the compilation.

Answer (score 4):

As remyabel indicated, you probably neglected to `#include <stdlib.h>`. The reason this matters is that, without having a declaration of `atof()`, the C standard mandates that the return value is assumed to be `int`. In this case, it's not `int`, which means that the actual behavior you observe (getting a return value of `0`) is technically unspecified.

To be clear, without the `double`-returning declaration, the line `ddd=atof(argv[1])` is treated as a call to an `int`-returning function, whose result is then cast to a `double`. It is likely the case that the calling conventions on the particular system you're on specify that `int`s and `double`s get returned in different registers, so the `0` is likely just to be whatever happened to be in that particular register, while the `double` return value is languishing, unobserved.

Answer (score 2):

In C you don't require to declare a function before you use it (in contrast with C++), and if that happens (no prototype), compiler makes some assumptions about that function. One of those assumptions is that it returns `int`. There's no error, `atof()` works, but it works incorrectly. It typically get whatever value happens to be in the register where `int` is supposed to be returned (it is 0 in your case, but it can be something else).

P.S. `atof()` and `atoi()` hide input errors (which you can always see by adding option -Wall to your gcc compiler call: `gcc -Wall test.c`), so most people prefer to use `strtol()` and `strtod()` instead.